# Google sheets query formula

Tags: google-sheets

I need to import from one google sheets tab to another just specific columns like in the formula below and it works. But from column E I need to import only specific values like 409, 753, 740 etc. Also from column G I only require values that state “Needed”.

=QUERY(CSV!A:J, "SELECT D, F, E, B, G”)

Any good tips how I could include this in the formula? Any tips/ ideas much appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

> from column E I need to import only specific values like 409, 753, 740 etc. Also from column G I only require values that state “Needed”.

Try this out:

```
=QUERY(CSV!A:J, "SELECT D, F, E, B, G where G = 'Needed' and E matches '409|753|740'”)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn’t work for either columns. I can use where if there is just one value, but I need to pull many different values from column E.

Comment: you should consider sharing a sample sheet.